# Installing XML::LibXML Perl module for ActiveState Perl Version 5.6.1 build 629

Tags: perl

How can I install XML::LibXML Perl module on ActiveState Perl Version 5.6.1 build 629?

Here what I tried:

```
D:\Users\abc>ppm install XML::LibXML
Installing package 'XML-LibXML'...
Error installing package 'XML-LibXML': Could not locate a PPD file for package XML-LibXML
```

And  other way:

```
D:\Users\abc\Downloads\XML-LibXML-2.0014\XML-LibXML-2.0014>perl Makefile.PL
Couldn't find your C compiler
Compilation failed in require at Makefile.PL line 83.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 83.
```

Comment: Well -- do you have a C compiler installed? (Is it on the %PATH%?)

Comment: Does Perl require C compiler?
I installed XML::LibXML Perl module for Perl Version 5.14.x without C compiler, it worked.
I installed using ppm.

Comment: Perl doesn't, per se, but some modules contain C code (which interfaces to perl via XS) that needs to be compiled. XML::LibXML is one of those modules. ActiveState maintains a set of pre-compiled libraries for each possible platform, so that you can just drop them in without compiling -- but it apparently doesn't have one for the version you're using. You can install Microsoft Visual C++ Express for free, which contains a C compiler.

Comment: Would you consider using a version of Perl that isn't twelve years old? I'm sure there are versions of ActivePerl more recent than that and it's probably worth looking at Strawberry Perl or DWIM Perl as well.

Comment: I just tried this with the latest ActiveState perl, and the command given works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed the CPAN version of PPM on my machine;
Downloaded the `PPM-2.1.8.tar.gz` source, extracted the files, made `cd` into the unpacked directory, and run

```
perl Makefile.PL 
nmake 
nmake install
```

But the `nmake` was not installed on my machine so I installed it.
After this, I able to install XML-LibXML from the uwinnipeg 5.6 repository by issuing the command

```
ppm install http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/ppmpackages/XML-LibXML.ppd
```

It also installed the prerequisite ppm packages, as well as the required `libxml2.dll` library in the environment variable PATH.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your ppm package manager is not able to find a correct package to your perl version.

You could try to find and install like one this. Maybe one of them works for you.

```
ppm install http://www.bribes.org/perl/ppm/XML-LibXML.ppd    
ppm install http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/ppmpackages/XML-LibXML.ppd
ppm install http://trouchelle.com/ppm/XML-LibXML.ppd
ppm install http://ppm.tcool.org/archives/XML-LibXML.ppd
ppm install http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/ppms/XML-LibXML.ppd
```

Howto add a new repo too ppm: http://www.bribes.org/perl/ppmdir.html